# Merging Two Batch Files

Tags: batch-file

I have two batch files. This is one of them:

```
:: Create a list of all the jpg's in the folder
dir /b > List.txt

:: Create a new folder for each jpg with the same name as the jpg
for %%i in (*.jpg) do mkdir "%%~ni"

:: Move all the jpg's into the newly created folders
for %%i in (*.jpg) do move "%%i" "%%~ni"

:: Duplicate the jpg's in the folders and add "-original" onto the end
for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do copy "%%~f" "%%~dpnf-original%%~xf"

:: Copy csv into new folders with same file name as the jpg's
for /D %%a in ("*") do copy /y /d C:\Projects\test.csv "%%a\%%a.csv"
```

This is the other:

```
:: Replace string in csv with csv file name and overwite csv file
for /R %%i in (*.csv) do (
ren "%%~i" temp.tmp
(for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ("%%~dpitemp.tmp") do (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:REPLACE=%%~ni!"
        echo(!line!
)) > "%%~i"
del "%%~dpitemp.tmp"
)
```

If I run the first, then the second it works fine. But then I try this to merge them into one batch file:

```
:: Create a list of all the jpg's in the folder
dir /b > List.txt

:: Create a new folder for each jpg with the same name as the jpg
for %%a in (*.jpg) do mkdir "%%~na"

:: Move all the jpg's into the newly created folders
for %%a in (*.jpg) do move "%%a" "%%~na"

:: Duplicate the jpg's in the folders and add "-original" onto the end
for /R %%b in (*.jpg) do copy "%%~b" "%%~dpnb-original%%~xb"

:: Copy csv into new folders with same file name as the jpg's
for /D %%c in ("*") do copy /Y /D C:\Projects\test.csv "%%c\%%c.csv"

:: Replace string in csv with csv file name and overwite csv file
for /R %%i in (*.csv) do (
ren "%%~i" temp.tmp
(for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ("%%~dpitemp.tmp") do (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:REPLACE=%%~ni!"
        echo(!line!
)) > "%%~i"
del "%%~dpitemp.tmp"
)
```

And I get this echoed in my csv file:

```
C:\Projects\Test>(
set "line=﻿REPLACE"  
 set "line=!line:REPLACE=NEWNAME!"  
 echo(!line! 
) 
!line!
```

The NEWNAME is whats meant to replace the REPLACE. I've made sure there's no variables being used twice, so i'm a little unsure why this is happening.

Comment: did you miss `@echo off` and `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` or did you just not show it here?

Comment: Thanks Stephan, It didn't work initially so I thought they were the issue, but I've since put them back in and it seems to be working. I didn't actually know removeing the `@echo off` could break it.

Comment: without `echo off` it will write each command as it is executed (called `command repetition`) If you redirect the output to a file, of course those repetitions are copied too.

Comment: Ahh right, okay great. Thanks for the info (:

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with adding the echo off, setlocal lines and endlocal.

```
:: Create a list of all the jpg's in the folder
dir /b > List.txt

:: Create a new folder for each jpg with the same name as the jpg
for %%a in (*.jpg) do mkdir "%%~na"

:: Move all the jpg's into the newly created folders
for %%a in (*.jpg) do move "%%a" "%%~na"

:: Duplicate the jpg's in the folders and add "-original" onto the end
for /R %%b in (*.jpg) do copy "%%~b" "%%~dpnb-original%%~xb"

:: Copy csv into new folders with same file name as the jpg's
for /D %%c in ("*") do copy /Y /D C:\Projects\test.csv "%%c\%%c.csv"

:: Replace string in csv with csv file name and overwite csv file
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%i in (*.csv) do (
ren "%%~i" temp.tmp
(for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ("%%~dpitemp.tmp") do (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:REPLACE=%%~ni!"
        echo(!line!
)) > "%%~i"
del "%%~dpitemp.tmp"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: As I said in your previous question, your code is super inefficient. You could combine the first 4 `FOR` commands into one.

Comment: I know it's not great, but I hardly ever use batch files so I was focused on getting it working. Now I know it works I can look into imporving it with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood but I think that this may be both of your posted scripts together as a single script:

```bat
@Echo Off
>"List.txt" (For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where .:*.jpg') Do (Echo %%~nxA
        XCopy "%%A" "%%~dpnA\"&&Move /Y "%%A" "%%~dpnA\%%~nA-original%~xA">Nul
        (For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%B In ("C:\Projects\test.csv") Do (
                Set "_=%%B"&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                Echo=!_:/REPLACE-=/%%~nA-!&EndLocal))>"%%~dpnA\%%~nA.csv"))
```

It is untested, *(and I've no intention of extending it beyond what I understood your two individual scripts were doing in your question at the time of this answer)*. If my understanding was wrong though, please provide feedback.

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to combine my script. I just tried it and it nearly works, but it doesn't duplicate the jpg properly (you only get the one with "-original" on the end), and the csv file ends up with "REPLACE" inside it. I don't understand that code well enough to look for why it doesn't work, but thanks for the effort (:

Comment: @Siwap, it was my misunderstanding, I thought you wanted just the `.jpg` moving into a new directory, _named with its filename_, but with `-original` inserting between its previous filename and its extension. So you are copying it as well as creating a backup with `-original` appended! **I have edited my code to cater for that misunderstanding**. As for having a `.csv` file with `REPLACE` inside it, just looking at the script content I cannot see how that is possible, unless you've made a modification, and done so incorrectly!